# javascript- function not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a html page with a button whos onclick calls a javascript function...but I have been getting a function not defined error for two days! Can someone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

        <head>
                 <meta charset="utf-8">
                 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.css" />
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-docs.css"/>

                 <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
                 <script src="js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
                 <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.js"></script>
                 <script>
                      function doSomething(){
                         alert('this is a test');
                      }
                </script>
         </head>
         <body>
           <div data-role="dialog">    
                <div data-role="content" id = "test" data-theme="c">
                <a href="$callback" data-role="button" data-theme="b" onClick = "doSomething();return true;" rel = "external">$confirm</a>
               <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
               </div>
          </div>
         </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are all those quotes escaped?

Comment: the entire thing is in a perl script, thats why. in the scipt its print" <html>....</html>";

Comment: this is pretty enough `onClick = \"doSomething();\"`  Also you have a `href` with that `a` tag.  This may affect.

Comment: Your browser doesn’t “see” Perl and does therefor not care for it, and neither do we. You want to discuss a _client-side_ problem, so please show the _client-side_ code as well, and not something _server-side_.

Comment: Ehh.. you do realize that you can use `qq` and chose the quoting characters yourself instead of having to always escape `"`

Comment: @user1671639 the return true statement doesnt affect the error.

Comment: @CBroe this IS the client-side code...its the HTML and JS code that the browser sees...

Comment: Well then it is _invalid_ HTML.

Comment: Removed the escape characters. WHat else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be handy:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

You need to stick your `scripts` within the `page` element:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <script>
        function doSomething(){
            alert('this is a test');
        }
    </script>
    <!-- the rest of your stuff -->
</div>
```

Comment: thankyou!!! I had to put the javascript within the PAGE element of the parent of the dialog box. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

In fact i have passed personally with this error even with valide HTML all what you need to do is move all of your functions to the `head` element.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WekEA/1/

To demonstate what i have said in the framework & change the `NoWrapToHead` to `onload`