# How do I put variable data into a div Jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to get the variables from my form and put them in a div but for some reason it wont work, please help
for some reason the way I do it does work for a normal HTML page, so I am not sure how to make it work for a Jquery mobile page

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link href="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="../jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page_home">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li><a href="#page_form">Form</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page_div">Div</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page_info">Info</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page_form">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <a href="#back" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-role="button">terug</a>

  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
  <form id="filldiv">
    <input type="text" id="div1" /> 
    <input type="text" id="div2" /> 
    <input type="text" id="div3" /> 
    <button onclick="ChangeText(); return false;">Submit</button>
  </form>l
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page_info">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <a href="#back" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-role="button">terug</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page_div">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <a href="#back" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-role="button">terug</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div class="empty" id="Div5">
    Text goes here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
function ChangeText()
{
            // Plaats de tekst in de pagina
            var test1 = document.getElementById('div1').value;
            var test2 = document.getElementById('div2').value;
            var test3 = document.getElementById('div3').value;
            var test = test1 + "</br>" + test2 + "</br>" + test3;
            document.getElementById('Div5').innerHTML = test;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of this question: [javascript- function not defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659151/javascript-function-not-defined-error)

try this:

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page_form">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <a href="#back" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-role="button">terug</a>

      </div>
      <div data-role="main">
      <form id="filldiv">
        <input type="text" id="div1" /> 
        <input type="text" id="div2" /> 
        <input type="text" id="div3" /> 
        <button onclick="ChangeText(); return false;">Submit</button>
      </form>l
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
      </div>
      <div data-role="page">
        <script>
            function ChangeText()
            {
              // Plaats de tekst in de pagina
              var test1 = document.getElementById('div1').value;
              var test2 = document.getElementById('div2').value;
              var test3 = document.getElementById('div3').value;
              var test = test1 + "</br>" + test2 + "</br>" + test3;
              document.getElementById('Div5').innerHTML = test;
            }
        </script>
        <!-- the rest of your stuff -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use innerHtml or text instead of value on your selected element/div.

Comment: document.getElementById('Div5').innerHTML = test;
You mean like that? like I have

Comment: No. Your variable test is empty. I mean to select the value for test123... You could use console.log() to check the values of your variables in every line.

Comment: Well if it were empty it would replace the text in the div with emptiness, right now it just doesnt do anything